# Change Background of css font code

Tags: css

I'm really new in this so, maybe you can help me!
I'm trying to change a background of this css, but I could not. Help me please!

P.s I just copy an example of other web page, so don't be extrange if you see something wrong please. (if you can't see the web page, maybe you should take a look over here https://www.charitywater.org/donate/#step-1) Just want to change the first big background and the last big background.
The css code:

Comment: It looks like you have an `!important` rule on your background property on the `<body>`, so you'll need to add another one to override it

Answer (score 1):

When you say "first big background", I am assuming you mean the people in the background.  If so, go into your style sheet (https://d555kv4p2mtwa.cloudfront.net/_site/styles/stylesheets/microsites/donate.css?v=10)
  and modify the background property for `.form-general{}`

I was able to detect that image right away with Developer Tools for Google Chrome.